# Convert Month Name to Date / Month Number (Combinations of Questions & Answers)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I had a look at numerous answer to my question, but none really answered my question.

I have data:

```
cBatchDesc  idBatches
Journal Batch - March 2017  88
Journal Batch - April 2017  2
Journal Batch - May 2017    3
Journal Batch - June 2017   4
Journal Batch - July 2017   5
Journal Batch - August 2017 6
Journal Batch - September 2017  7
Journal Batch - October 2017    8
Journal Batch - November 2017   9
Journal Batch - December 2017   10
Journal Batch - January 2018    11
Journal Batch - February 2018   12
Journal Batch - March 2017  89
Journal Batch - April 2017  13
Journal Batch - May 2017    14
Journal Batch - June 2017   15
Journal Batch - July 2017   16
Journal Batch - August 2017 17
Journal Batch - September 2017  18
Journal Batch - October 2017    19
Journal Batch - November 2017   20
Journal Batch - December 2017   21
Journal Batch - January 2018    22
Journal Batch - February 2018   23
Journal Batch - March 2017  90
Journal Batch - April 2017  27
Journal Batch - May 2017    28
Journal Batch - June 2017   29
Journal Batch - July 2017   30
Journal Batch - August 2017 31
Journal Batch - September 2017  32
Journal Batch - October 2017    33
Journal Batch - November 2017   34
Journal Batch - December 2017   35
Journal Batch - January 2018    36
Journal Batch - February 2018   37
```

I needed to convert the date name at the end of `cBatchDesc` to the Actual Date.

Comment: Do you really have "Journal Batch - " at the beginning of every single row in the table? That is redundant and forces you to use denormalized tables. If at all possible you should change your table structure and store dates in the date datatype. Then you can avoid all of this hassle.

Comment: @SeanLange, unfortunately I cannot change the table, due to the software using it, it has to stay that way. But thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, people would be a whole lot more willing to help if the data you post is "Readily Consumable", like the following...

```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestTable;
GO
 SELECT  v.cBatchDesc, v.idBatches
   INTO #TestTable
   FROM (VALUES  
         ('Journal Batch - March 2017'    ,88)
        ,('Journal Batch - April 2017'    ,2 )
        ,('Journal Batch - May 2017'      ,3 )
        ,('Journal Batch - June 2017'     ,4 )
        ,('Journal Batch - July 2017'     ,5 )
        ,('Journal Batch - August 2017'   ,6 )
        ,('Journal Batch - September 2017',7 )
        ,('Journal Batch - October 2017'  ,8 )
        ,('Journal Batch - November 2017' ,9 )
        ,('Journal Batch - December 2017' ,10)
        ,('Journal Batch - January 2018'  ,11)
        ,('Journal Batch - February 2018' ,12)
        ,('Journal Batch - March 2017'    ,89)
        ,('Journal Batch - April 2017'    ,13)
        ,('Journal Batch - May 2017'      ,14)
        ,('Journal Batch - June 2017'     ,15)
        ,('Journal Batch - July 2017'     ,16)
        ,('Journal Batch - August 2017'   ,17)
        ,('Journal Batch - September 2017',18)
        ,('Journal Batch - October 2017'  ,19)
        ,('Journal Batch - November 2017' ,20)
        ,('Journal Batch - December 2017' ,21)
        ,('Journal Batch - January 2018'  ,22)
        ,('Journal Batch - February 2018' ,23)
        ,('Journal Batch - March 2017'    ,90)
        ,('Journal Batch - April 2017'    ,27)
        ,('Journal Batch - May 2017'      ,28)
        ,('Journal Batch - June 2017'     ,29)
        ,('Journal Batch - July 2017'     ,30)
        ,('Journal Batch - August 2017'   ,31)
        ,('Journal Batch - September 2017',32)
        ,('Journal Batch - October 2017'  ,33)
        ,('Journal Batch - November 2017' ,34)
        ,('Journal Batch - December 2017' ,35)
        ,('Journal Batch - January 2018'  ,36)
        ,('Journal Batch - February 2018' ,37)
        )v(cBatchDesc,idBatches)
;
```

I'm glad you solved it on your own but you can make things a little more flexible by calculating the position of the "-" so you can handle other descriptions, should they occur.

Also, you can "DRY" (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself) your code out (to make it easier to read/change) by calculating the date just once for each row using a CROSS APPLY like this (note that you didn't provide a cBatchNo column so the ORDER BY is different and I didn't display the SUBSTRING)...

```
 SELECT  cBatchDesc
        ,MonthNumber = DATEPART(mm,ca.Date)
        ,MonthStart  = ca.Date
        ,MonthEnd    = EOMONTH(ca.Date)
        ,idBatches
   FROM #TestTable
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(cBatchDesc,CHARINDEX('-',cBatchDesc)+1,100)))ca(Date)
  ORDER BY ca.Date, idBatches
;
```

For the data you provided, that provides the following (truncated) results ...

[image]

Comment: Thanks @JeffModen, this is a better answer!

Answer (score 3):

After reading through a lot of people's posts, I managed to come up with the following Code:

```
select
    cBatchDesc
,   substring(cBatchDesc,16,100)    [SUBSTRING]
,   datepart(MM,substring(cBatchDesc,16,100))   [DATEPART]
,   cast(substring(cBatchDesc,16,100) as date)  [CAST]
,   eomonth(cast(substring(cBatchDesc,16,100) as date)) [EOMONTH]
,   idBatches
from    _btblJrBatches
order by cBatchNo
```

As can be noticed, I had to separate the month from the rest of the Description using `SUBSTRING`.

From there, I get the month number using `DATEPART`.

Using `CAST`, I was able to convert the Month Name to `DATE`.

I then needed the end of that month, which you'll see I used `EOMONTH`.

See below results :

[image]

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Since you are converting a string (which is risky), I would suggest using try_convert() or try_cast().  It will not throw an error if the conversion fails in the future... i.e. unexpected data / format change

Comment: @Birel, Great, that you've found your own answer (Upvote from my side)! Just one hint: This relys on your system's language settings. If there is a risk, that this logic might run on international systems in future, think about this. On my system ("October" would be "Oktober") this would fail...

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, thanks for your comment. I agree it's risky, but the data wouldn't change, so it's not that risky :-). I am however using `CAST`