# Correct way to convert Month Name and Year to complete date SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have data in the format below.

```
January 2016
August 2017
November 2018
January 2018
August 2018
November 2018
```

I now want to convert this to a valid datetime value so i use the column as a proper date in reports.

My plan is to just add the first (or even better) the last day of the month. 
I have tried the below code, it seems to work but i'm wondering if there could be a better way.

```
DATEADD(dd, -Day(b.MonthYear) + 1, b.MonthYear)
```

With the above code, `August 20117` gives me `2017-08-01 00:00:00.000` but maybe there could be a better way.

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595777/convert-month-name-to-date-month-number-combinations-of-questions-answers/53595778#53595778)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's as simple as this:

```
SELECT CAST ('January 2016' AS DATETIME)
```

Or for SQL2012+

```
SELECT TRY_CAST ('January 2016' AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: try_convert() or try_cast() would be safer considering the risk of string conversion  +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti you are right, but it depends on version. Thanks for the comment, updated my answer.

Comment: This is relying on your systems default language to be *english*. A very dangerous assumption... You might read my answer...

Answer (score 4):

The source of danger here his: You are relying on your system's culture.

Culture-dependant date formats are dangerous (What is `10/09/2017`? Is it 9th of Oct or 10th of Sep?). But even worse are language dependant formats (October is Oktober in my country).

Try this

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
SELECT TRY_CAST('January 2017' AS DATE),TRY_CONVERT(DATE,'January 2017')

SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
SELECT TRY_CAST('January 2017' AS DATE),TRY_CONVERT(DATE,'January 2017')
```

The alternative calls without the `TRY_` would not return `NULL` but throw an error.

But you are stating `[sql-server-2014]`. That means [you can use `TRY_PARSE()` (v2012+)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). The big advantage: You can specify the underlying culture.

```
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN
SELECT TRY_PARSE('January 2017' AS DATE USING 'en-us')
```

If there is the smallest chance, that you code might ever run in international environments you should **never ever rely on the default culture**...

### UPDATE performance vs. stability...

In a comment I answered @SQL_M:

> I know what I'd choose... If dates are properly handled, you'd never
>   have to deal with such a question. We should see textual formats in
>   output only. The user's input should be handled by the application
>   layer. So the database should never have to think about such
>   conversions. The fact, that this need exists, shows clearly, that the
>    database/application was not designed properly. We should not add more
>   weakness if we can avoid it

This made me curious and I did some tests.

I must admit: The performance difference is undeniable and much bigger than expected. On a million rows with dates like `Jan  1 1900 12:11AM` (default with `CONVERT`, param 100) I get:

- TRY_CONVERT about 600ms
- TRY_CAST about 550ms
- TRY_PARSE about 45.000ms

So yes, it is really worth to be aware of the performance impact (~x100). But the statement above still remains true.

The test code - if interested:

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE testDB
GO
USE testDB
GO
CREATE TABLE testTbl(ID INT IDENTITY,DateString VARCHAR(100));
GO
WITH Tally(Nmbr) AS (SELECT TOP 1000000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values v1 CROSS JOIN master..spt_values v2 CROSS JOIN master..spt_values)
INSERT INTO testTbl(DateString)
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(MINUTE,t.Nmbr,'19000101'),100)
FROM Tally t;
GO
CHECKPOINT;
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO
DECLARE @d DATETIME2=SYSUTCDATETIME();
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME,DateString) AS d INTO t1 FROM testTbl;
SELECT 'TRY_CONVERT', DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@d,SYSUTCDATETIME());
GO
CHECKPOINT;
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO
DECLARE @d DATETIME2=SYSUTCDATETIME();
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME,DateString,100) AS d INTO t2 FROM testTbl;
SELECT 'TRY_CONVERT with 3rd param', DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@d,SYSUTCDATETIME());
GO
CHECKPOINT;
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO
DECLARE @d DATETIME2=SYSUTCDATETIME();
SELECT TRY_PARSE(DateString AS DATETIME) AS d INTO t3 FROM testTbl;
SELECT 'TRY PARSE',DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@d,SYSUTCDATETIME());
GO
CHECKPOINT;
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO
DECLARE @d DATETIME2=SYSUTCDATETIME();
SELECT TRY_PARSE(DateString AS DATETIME USING 'de-de') AS d INTO t4 FROM testTbl;
SELECT 'TRY PARSE with culture',DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@d,SYSUTCDATETIME());
GO
CHECKPOINT;
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO
DECLARE @d DATETIME2=SYSUTCDATETIME();
SELECT TRY_CAST(DateString AS DATETIME) AS d INTO t5 FROM testTbl;
SELECT 'TRY_CAST',DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@d,SYSUTCDATETIME());

GO
USE master;
GO
DROP DATABASE testDB;
```

Comment: Plus one, useful addition to my post.

Comment: @SQL_M To be honest: In my eyes this is not a *useful addition to your post*, but the only reliable answer. Your approach might work perfectly, pass all internal tests, and might still break in production environment with unexpected, silly and hard-to-find errors...

Comment: Reliable yes. But bear in mind, if you do not work in an international environment,  this solution is not desirable. Your solution always works, but comes at a cost (performance takes a hit).

Comment: Nice tests, I did a few tests myself a while back and got similar results. As you said, differences are much bigger than you would expect.